# Axis2 client. Log shows lots of "Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.4.1 - file:/C:/path/to/mex-1.4.1.jar" lines

Tags: module, logging, apache-axis, deploying

I'm using an Axis2 soap client from an j2se application that is always running. I'm getting a lot of lines like these in my log files:

*INFO   | jvm 1 |.. Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.4.1 - file:/C:/path/to/mex-1.4.1.jar*

Looks like a lot of these lines will appear every time the code for consuming the webservice runs.
I wanted to know if this can cause a problem in the long run to the application or if it's safe to ignore the log messages (all of them are at INFO level).

Axis2 version is 1.6.1. I generated the stubs using wsdl2java and put the axis libs in the classpath. The code runs fine but I would like to know why it deploys this module every time and if it affects performance.

Right now I'm having OutOfMemory errors and I need to discard all the possibilities to fix this problem.

Thanks a lot.